# Sonicwall TZ205 with EnGenius ESB300 as Guest Wireless AP, Need to keep networks apart

Tags: networking, firewall, routing, sonicwall, access-point

I have a SonicWall TZ205 with an EnGenius ESB300 as a Guest Wireless AP.  I would like to keep these networks segregated.

Interface X0 is the LAN, X1 is WAN and the EnGenius is connected to X4 in AP Router mode.  The LAN subnet is 192.168.1.0 and is configured to DHCP.  The EnGenius is seeing a WAN IP of 192.168.1.24 and the subnet on the EnGenius is 10.0.0.0 and is set to DHCP to the wireless clients.  What I'm seeing is that the 10.0.0.x clients can see the 192. network but not the other way.  I would like to have all traffic from the EnGenius on X4 routed to the WAN for Internet but be unable to interact with the 192 network.  I've tried setting up a firewall rule on the Sonicwall to deny traffic from 192.168.1.24 to the LAN interface but that didn't seem to have any effect.  This seems like basic routing but I can't seem to get it to work.

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Can post routing tables and config settings if needed.

Comment: You can't use a SonicPoint ? without an sonicpoint, you need to define a zone on your port, I would not route but put in bridge mode your access-point, an example there to create a new zone (https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28240877/Sonicwall-TZ-105-configuration-for-Multiple-LAN-s.html)